# While click on button window scroll down to a section id through custom JS in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to edit a section but that section is very bottom in a page when I click on edit button user doesn't understand where the edit section so I have used a simple JS for this. But I got an error can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Here is code :

```js
/*--JS--*/

$("#edit_me").on("click" ,function(){
 scrolled=scrolled-300;
    $("#section-2").animate({
  scrollBottom:  scrolled
 });
});
```

```css
/*--CSS--*/
 
   .box-1{padding:15%;}
   #edit_me{
    background:green; 
    padding:6px 12px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
       color:#fff;
   }
   #section-1, #section-2{min-height:300px; border:solid 3px #000;}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <a href="section-2" class="btn edit_me" id="edit_me">Edit</a> 
 <div id="section-1"> 
  <div class="container">
   <div class="box-1">
    <h1>SECTION-1</h1>
   </div>
  <div>
 <div>
 <div id="section-2">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="box-1">
    <h1>SECTION-2</h1>
   </div>
  <div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is `scrolled` variable? Where you define it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use id for that, please check the updated post. It will scroll up to the particular position wherever the edit section is placed.

---

```js
$('.click_to_scroll').click(function(){
var clickedId = $(this).attr('href');
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(clickedId).offset().top)} , 1000);
return false;
});
```

```css
#edit {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 800px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#edit" class="click_to_scroll">edit</a>

<div id="edit">
</div>
```

Comment: @Bhargav Ohh really, I have worked 3 years and i have implemented it same in other projects, if not so i can list you them, Shame on such thoughts.

Comment: but this answer already given by 18 min ago and then write you same after thats why ... thanks for reply

Comment: Did i got teach from you about how to write jquery.... If it is then i am happy. I have my thoughts of writing it in my own way and if you compare it is far different than your code.

Comment: ya sure if you like to learn its good , i am always ready to teach any child who want to learn...;-)

Comment: We all are kids, Study never ends, no matter how big scholar you are :-)

Comment: Don't quarrel here on this community guys!! Anyway thanks both of you!

Comment: Great display of character @Sangrai

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```js
$("#edit_me").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section-2").offset().top
    }, 2500);
});
```

```css
.box-1 {
  padding: 15%;
}

#edit_me {
  background: green;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

#section-1,
#section-2 {
  min-height: 300px;
  border: solid 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn edit_me" id="edit_me">Edit</a>
<div id="section-1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-1">
      <h1>SECTION-1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div id="section-2" name='section-2'>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="box-1">
              <h1>SECTION-2</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I want to scroll it slowly not so fast

Comment: but you dont tell about this in your question so first thing what you want exactly and than ask...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `scrolled` is not defined. You need to put a start value to it, but you can always use this function to scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
  $('html, body').animate(
    {scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow'
  );
```